# 12V Relay not clicking

Tags: arduino-uno

Trying to power the 12V relay from an Arduino to make an automatic cocktail maker.  Looking to power 12V water pumps off of the relay.  However, the relay is not clicking, only getting the light.

The connections FROM the Arduino TO the relay is as follows:

| Arduino | Relay |
| --- | --- |
| 5V | VCC |
| GND | GND |
| pin 3 | IN1 |

Also pictures of circuit are provided. The Arduino is powered by USB laptop.

[image: Relay]
[image: Arduino]
[image: Test code]

Comment: Have you set pin 3 to be an output?

Comment: What kind of relay or relay module are you using?

Comment: 12V relay controlled by 5V arduino? You need a 5V relay or 12V supply for relay.

Comment: True, if you already connected the relay to pin 3, just test if the pin is still working as it might have drawn too much current, you should use a 5v relay or a 12 volt power source with a transistor.

Comment: The O.P. had intended to include more than the one image, but their markdown had been mangled.  Corrected, you can see this answers the pinMode question by Majenko and gives at least some degree of answer for StarCat.

Comment: @SBF, the relay board image that wasn't rendering in the [original post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/revisions/84791/1) confirms for you.

Comment: The `digitalWrite()` commands in your code use “quoted” values (such as `“LOW”` and `“HIGH”`) for the second operand. I dont’t think that will work correctly. Try to use the conventional `LOW` and `HIGH`. For example `digitalWrite(relay, HiGH)`.

Comment: [Please see why we shouldn't post images of text :)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

After search the internet,
i believe the 12v relay need 12v to click.

You may check these :

https://handtoolsforfun.com/how-to-connect-a-12v-relay-board-to-arduino/

https://www.instructables.com/Connecting-a-12V-Relay-to-Arduino/

Comment: The problem is, we have no idea which relay board is used. The first link you point to whoes a relay board that looks like the one in the question but then goes on to explain nothing about that boards’ particulars. It even shows a relay controlled by a transistor, without the optical isolators that are clearly on the board. However, I think these relay boards do need a +12V connection.